# Show Login Dialog Before Application

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

What I want to achieve is pretty simple: I want the user to not be able to see application when he is not logged in.

So what I need to do is to show a login dialog, then create the application. I tried to do just that in `IApplication#start(IApplicationContext)`, but that method is evidently not run in the UI thread, so I had no luck getting dialogs to show up there.

Afterwards I tried `WorkbenchAdvisor#preStartup()`:

```
public void preStartup() {
    if (openLoginDialog() != Window.OK) {
        getWorkbenchConfigurer().emergencyClose();
    }
}
```

I don't think `emergencyClose()` is the right method to call here, but `IWorkbench#close()` throws a `NullPointerException` and still opens a window stub.

Well, `emergencyClose()` throws `NullPointerException` as well, but other than that works as expected:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.busyClose(Workbench.java:1204)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$22(Workbench.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$19.run(Workbench.java:1454)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.close(Workbench.java:1451)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchConfigurer.emergencyClose(WorkbenchConfigurer.java:159)
at org.acme.project.ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor.preStartup(ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor.java:36)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$24.runWithException(Workbench.java:1718)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:32)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2989)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$9(Workbench.java:2894)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:685)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
```

Is there a way to prevent that exception? Or is there a better way to open a login dialog before the first application window gets opened?

Comment: People mostly seem to use the Splash screen for login. There is a template for this on the 'Splash' tab of the xxx.product file editor (never tried it myself).

Comment: @greg-449 That's a great feature. Horrible GUI support, but great feature. Now it works as expected, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can call some method on UI thread in IApplication#start(IApplicationContext) like this. But I'm not sure this is the right way.

```
final int[] result = new int[]{0};
Display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
    result[0] = new YourLoginDialog(Display.getCurrent().getShell()).open();
});
if (result[0] != Windows.OK) {
    // failed to login
    return IApplicaton.EXIT_OK;
}
```

Comment: check your IApplication#start method, you might find some method creates display.